# How to get text of a radiobutton, which created dynamically by C#, in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, radio-button

I am adding radiobuttons to my **HTML** page dynamically by **C#** via:

```
for (int i = 0; i < groupnames.Count; i++)
{
    HtmlTableRow row = new HtmlTableRow();
    HtmlTableCell cell = new HtmlTableCell();
    RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton();
    radioButton.ID = "rdDataGroup_" + i;
    radioButton.Text = groupnames[i].GroupName;
    radioButton.GroupName = "DataGroup";
    if (i==0)
    {
       radioButton.Checked = true;
    }
    cell.Controls.Add(radioButton);
    row.Cells.Add(cell);
    tblRadioButtonList.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

When I check my radiobutton items in web browser <kbd>F12</kbd>, I see like below:

[image]

My problem is, I could not manage to reach the text of the radiobutton(s) in **JavaScript**. Where is the Text attribute? How can I manage to get the text in JavaScript or jQuery? I have tried alerting those below, none of them worked.

```
document.getElementById("rdDataGroup_1").InnerHTML; //returns empty string
document.getElementById("rdDataGroup_1").InnerText; //returns empty string
document.getElementById("rdDataGroup_1").value; //returns id
$("input[name='DataGroup']:checked").data('name'); //undefined
$("input[name='DataGroup']:checked").parent('label').text(); //returns empty string
```

Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit1**: I am sure `groupnames[i].GroupName` is not empty string.

**Edit2**: Just tried `$("input[name='DataGroup']:checked").parent().text();` and it returned the text of selected radiobutton. Still not sure why `innerHtml` or `innerText` (also `.value`) did not work, but the jQuery helped.

**Edit3**: HTML follows:

```
<body>
    <form id="myForm" runat="server">
        <section class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-3">
                    <table id="tblRadioButtonList" runat="server"></table>
                    <div id="divFinding"></div>
                    <div id="divUnderstood"></div>
                    <div id="divImpactful"></div>
                </div>
            </div> 
        </section>
   <form>
<body>
```

Comment: It's `.innerHTML` and `.innerText` and `.InnerHTML;` won't ever return an _"empty string"_

Comment: Probably you have a textNode just after the radio button, or maybe a label.  Please, post more HTML related to that radiobutton.

Comment: @Ele There is no much html code, only <table id="tblRadioButtonList" runat="server"></table> in body.

Comment: In browser can you see the `groupnames[i].GroupName`?

Comment: @Ele yes I do see.

Comment: You say that document.getElementById("rdDataGroup_1").value;  returns the id but if I look at the html output you showed above, the value === the id. Are you sure its not actually outputting the value?

Comment: So, please inspect the HTML and share the markup close to that radiobutton.

Comment: $("input[name='DataGroup']:checked").parent().text()  returns the text of selected radiobutton, just I needed to use parent() instead of parent('label')

Comment: Because the parent it's probably a `label`.  The radiobutton doesn't have html as body.

Comment: html code added to question

Comment: The text you see with a radio button is never part of a radio button. it is not the inner text or inner html or inner anything. it is just a label or span or just a text block sitting next to the input tag. Look at the page source (F12) and look what is next to each radio button, outside the input tag.

Comment: Got it @Nawed, thanks for the clarification.